# jQuery ajax call in onunload handler firing AFTER getting the page on a manual refresh. How do I guarantee onunload happens first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh, onunload

I have a situation where on page unload I am firing a request to delete the draft of a user's work.  This works fine until a user chooses to refresh the page, whereupon inspecting Chrome's network tab shows that Chrome is loading the new page before the ajax request is actually fired.  The result is a new draft is created by the page load, and then deleted right away by the ajax call.  Here is basically what I'm doing:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if (pageUpdated){
        return 'Are you sure you want to abandon this draft?';
    }
}

window.onunload = function(){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/some/url/'
    });
}
```

Is there a way to force the onunload handler to complete before the request for the new page is sent?

Browsers Tested: (Chrome 9, FF 3.6) on Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid

Comment: Does this only occur in Chrome? Or does it also occur in FF, IE, Safari?

Answer (score 4):

In onbeforeunload or $.unload() set up your AJAX object with async = false.  This will make sure the ajax call completes before the page is unloaded.

I know this question is a few months old, but I wanted to add this info in case it helps anyone searching for a similar issue with AJAX!

Answer (score 3):

Making the XHR request synchronous should delay the loading of the new page until after the request is complete.  I don't know how jQuery runs its synchronous XHR requests under the hood, but here's how you can do it using plain JavaScript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// or new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") for some versions of IE
request.open("GET", "/some/url", false);
request.send(null);

var result = request.responseText;
alert(result);
```

Putting that in your unload handler should make the browser wait until "/some/url" is loaded before it moves on to the next page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm here to confirm @Silkster answer. I can fire an AJAX request after set an option async = false

Here is the example code.

```
$(window).unload( function () {
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        async: false  
    });
    $.get("target.php");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) instead, though I'm not sure if it's implemented in all browsers.

Comment: I'm already using onbeforeunload for a confirmation.  Edited code to reflect that.  Thanks!