# Problem with jquery ajax and google chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, onunload

I'm using jQuery to show a confirmation message for the user when leaving the page as follows:

```
var changes = false;  

window.onunload =function() { 
    if (changes) {
        $.post("check.php",{undovideokey:VID});
    } else return null; 
};
```

on the other hand

```
<input type='submit' name='Add' value='submit ' align='right' onclick="changes = true;" />
```

A problem occurs when running the code in Google Chrome when I refresh the page. I have seen many problems like this but there is not helpful answers.

[jQuery ajax call in onunload handler firing AFTER getting the page on a manual refresh. How do I guarantee onunload happens first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034216/jquery-ajax-call-in-onunload-handler-firing-after-getting-the-page-on-a-manual-re)

[window.onbeforeunload ajax request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-problem-with-chrome)

thanks,
Sara

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? I don't see a question in your post.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your issue that the AJAX request occurs *after* the page has been refreshed.

Changing the code to trigger on the `onbeforeunload` event and using a synchronous AJAX request should fix your problem:

```
var changes = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (changes) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "check.php",
            data: {
                undovideokey: 'foo'
            }
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    };
};
```

Note that this is difficult to see in Chrome's developer tools, since it does not persist AJAX requests across reloads. You should verify the behaviour on the server-side or by using a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wq4hk/4/show (Editable via http://jsfiddle.net/wq4hk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed browsers will attempt to maintain *to some extent* javascript state whenever you click the "refresh" button or press F5 (or whatever the heck it is on a mac).  When you're developing it's a really annoying feature because you want to start from a fresh state.  This may seem dumb but something I do to force a fresh state is to place my cursor in the address box and hit enter.  Chrome will then treat it as I'm starting a new session and not hold any lingering javascript state.  I've run into a lot of quirky behavior when just pressing F5 for code that depends on having a clean state and fresh events.

Comment: +1 for not knowing how to refresh a mac. i didn't know for the longest time, but apparently it's the apple key + R