# Data not passing through AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a value of a button using some ajax to a separate file.

Here is my code.

```
            $("input#downloadSingle").click(function() {
                var myData = $("input#downloadSingle").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url:'singleDownload.php',
                    data: myData,
                    success: function(results) {
                        alert('works');
                    }
                });
            });
```

However, when I test out the next page by doing a var_dump on $_POST. I don't get any data back. Thoughts?

Comment: What browser? What host (localhost?)? I guess Google Chrome ;)

Comment: Check the network tab of your debugger if it actually sends the data and if the server acknowledges it. Also check the console for errors.

Comment: There you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796087/problem-with-jquery-ajax-and-google-chrome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not specifying the name of the `$_POST` variable you're gonna get on the `singleDownload.php` file (unless that's part of the button's value), so you should try something like:

```
        $("input#downloadSingle").click(function() {
            var myData = "whatever=" + $("input#downloadSingle").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url:'singleDownload.php',
                data: myData,
                success: function(results) {
                    alert('works');
                }
            });
        });
```

And make sure `$_POST` in your php file is the same `whatever` variable

Comment: This worked for me. So, are we setting a post key here with whatever?